# Connecting to a secure, graphical, x session using a stateless thin client

Tags: linux, thin-client

I'm looking for an open source, non-proprietery solution to this problem, any help would be appreciated. I'd like to setup a server running Ubuntu Server. I'd then like to connect to this server from a stateless thin client and use an x-session. This would occur mostly over local area networks, but also possibly over the internet.

- What would be the ideal set of software to accomplish this from a security, and usability standpoint?
- Are there any ready-made stateless thin clients that don't require proprietery software?

Comment: LTSP.  http://www.ltsp.org/ Browse around their site for a links to vendors that sell hardware.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LTSP](http://www.ltsp.org) like Zoredache suggested in his comment would be my first choice.  Best options in terms of support and ease-of-setup/maintenance.

Using VNC (X2VNC or similar) and port forwarding over SSH would be my secondchoice.  See the [SSH man page](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html), specifically the part about port forwarding.

Another option would be a point-top-point VPN connectivity (so you could use the normal X11 remote session functionality)